# Nativescript advanced seed Android APK build size

Tags: nativescript

I'm using [Nativescript advanced seed](https://github.com/NathanWalker/angular-seed-advanced) project to start with a sample project. The sample project as is, got built and deployed to my device taking arround 100MB, which seems to be a lot considering no new screen added(except for the default 2 screens).

Is it because of the other platforms libs included in the base project?
Is there anyways to disable unused libs to reduce the apk size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not because of the other platform libs, which will not be included in your Android/iOS build. In other words,each platform build has its own command, which will include only that platform specific files. Ex. Mac related wont be present in the Android build.

App size is currently an issue with Nativescript. You might be doing a dev build. When you do PR build with below platform specific commands, base size will be around 50MB.

```
Android:   npm run build.android
iOS:       npm run build.ios
```

Size wont increase exponentially as you add new screens, as the most of the size is coming from nativescrit base web dependencies to execute the JS files in the run time.

More on webpack here -> https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/how-to-decrease-app-size-and-release-it-using-webpack-and-nativescript/798

Comment: So using webpack before PR build will bring the size further down from 50MB? Whats the least size we can get for Android?

Comment: @stackdeveloper corrected the answer. webpack is already used in the seed project build commands. Link for your understanding. As of now(Jan-2018) Nativescript app size is still a concern for some, considering min size would be around 50MB for PR build.

Comment: This link explain the three essential components included in the nativescript app which takes the major chunk in the app size. https://www.nativescript.org/blog/nativescript-android-application-package-size-revealed

Comment: Thank you. PR links helps to reduce. But still 50+MB might be a deal breaker for our requirement.